# How do you make Git work with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, git, version-control

I am going to use Git version control by IntelliJ Community Edition in order to make branches of the programs I intend to develop. I am striving to accustom myself to its functionality and I come accross obstacles.

I follow the instructions of the web-page  http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally and although I do what it orders, when I reach Image5 I find an empty list under Default.

It is possible that it does not matter I thought, so I continued the procedure.
However when I come to most important section of Committing Changes to Master (Revision 1) the list is also empty and the commit changes does not detect any changes to my project (see Image13 and Image 14).

Apart from that, I receive a message when I open the project  once more indicating that the Git execution path is not correct. But how can I get knowledge of what execution path should be appropriate so as to insert it?

Does anybody know a decent order of instructions (on a web site or by his won experience) which can guide me to how I can take advantage of Git functionality to incorporate it to my work? It is crucial for me to put my work through.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to specify the executable path of Git in the [Git Settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/git.html), as mentionned in the per-requesites:

> The [Git integration plugin is enabled](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-installing-and-uninstalling-plugins-from-jetbrains-plugin-repository.html) and the location of the Git executable file is correctly specified on the [Git page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/git.html) of the [Settings dialog box](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/settings-dialog.html).

As long as you see "a message indicating that the Git execution path is not correct", the rest  of the instructions won't work.

> **Path to Git executable**

> In this text box, specify the path to the Git executable file.
> Type the path manually or click the Browse button to open the `Select Path - Git Configuration` dialog box and select the location of the Git executable file in the directories tree.

See "[Where is git.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/6309)" for the path of Git on Windows.

- with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases):

  ```
    C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
  ```

OR

```
    c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit\usr\bin
```

OR

```
    c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.x.\mingw64\bin
```

- With [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/):

  ```
    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PORTAB~1\bin\git.exe
  ```

---

Update 2020, three years later:

As noted by [Daniel Connelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8651748/daniel-connelly) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671305/how-do-you-make-git-work-with-intellij/7671364#comment111659803_7671364)

> IntelliJ now lets people install it through the path specified in the help above (just look for the "`Download Now`" button on the Git menu).
> If you download Git from the website, a version that IntelliJ does not support will be installed.

Comment: OK, I have installed Git on a Git directory but I cannot find the executable file to set. What is that? Whatever I have tried has failed promting a window with a message "errors occuring while executing...".

Comment: @arjacsoh What is your Os? On Windows, you would have a `<git installation dir>/bin/git.exe`, making the `<git installation dir>/bin/` the directory to set.

Comment: Finally, I got it but I downloaded TortoiseGit and I installed this instead. I found the executable file and it works. The file you suggest works rather as well, but I did not try it. I 'll try it on my home PC. Thank you.

Comment: @arjacsoh: excellent. On Windows, you usually install msysgit. http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Comment: Yeah,https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ is getting more support so it should be a better choice.

Comment: An anonymous user [was trying to add](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8050802) 'Click fix_it. Then update the versionControl executable path. you can test with test options'

Comment: For me, pointing to git.exe under  `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` did the trick. Similar folder structure is present for Portable git version too

Comment: IntelliJ now lets people install it through the path specified in the help above (just look for the "Download Now" button on the `Git` menu. If you  download Git from the website, a version that IntelliJ does not support will be installed.

Comment: @DanielConnelly Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

GitHub for Windows on Windows 7 currently installs `Git` in a path similar to this:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_93e8418133eb85e81a81e5e19c272776524496c6\bin\git.exe
```

The guid after `PortableGit_` may well be different on your system.

Comment: But will the guid remain the same after a GitHub update?

Comment: Probably not...  I'd recommend using msysGit these days.  I probably haven't used GitHub for Windows since I posted this answer! :)

Answer (score 7):

On unix systems, you can use the following command to determine where git is installed:

```
whereis git
```

If you are using MacOS and did a recent update, it is possible you have to agree to the licence terms again. Try typing 'git' in a terminal, and see if you get the following message:

`Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.`

Answer (score 5):

On Window machine install any version of Git. I installed

> Git-2.14.1-64-bit.exe

. Got to  search program and search for git.exe. The file can be located under

> C:\Users\sd\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe

.

Open Intelli IDEA>Settings>Version Control>Git. On Path To Git executable add the path. Click on Test button. It will show a message as

> Git executed successfully

Now click on Apply and Save. This will solve the issue.
.

Comment: This option worked for me. We should not reference the downloaded file. Instead git.exe created after the install should be referenced in intellij.

Answer (score 1):

git.exe is common for any git based applications like GitHub, Bitbucket etc. Some times it is possible that you have already installed another git based application so git.exe will be present in the bin folder of that application.

For example if you installed bitbucket before github in your PC, you will find git.exe in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin`
instead of `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit.....\bin`.

Comment: Atlassian SourceTree's git.exe is most easily found in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users, check the value of `GIT_HOME` in your `.env` file in the home directory.

1. Open terminal
2. Type `cd home/<username>/`
3. Open the `.env` file and check the value of `GIT_HOME` and select the git path appropriately

PS: If you are not able to find the `.env` file, click on `View` on the formatting tool bar, select `Show hidden files`. You should be able to find the `.env` file now.

Comment: Ad 2: You only need to type `cd` (without any parameters) to change to your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, just restarted IntelliJ after it kept showing this "install git" message after I have pressed and installed git, and it disappeared, and git works