# Where is git.exe located?

Tags: windows, git, github-for-windows

I have PyCharm and I am looking around trying to find git.exe to set it up with my repo.

What is the PATH to git.exe?

Comment: Why not just run a search for filename "git.exe?"

Comment: @DavidCain: When I do a search for "git.exe" on my C: drive it finds 10 copies of that file. It looks like most of them are the same, but a couple of them are very small, presumably shortcut files?

Comment: @DavidCain: When I do the search, it wouldn't find it since the binaries are placed in a hidden folder (../AppData/..) which is not within the scope of the default search parameters.

Comment: On my Windows 10 system, git 2.19.0 used to be located in `C:/Program Files/Git/`, but after updating to git 2.19.1 using `git update-git-for-windows`, it was moved to `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/`. This caused PyCharm to complain about not finding `git.exe`. Found it again by running `where git.exe` in git bash, as suggested in the answers below.

Comment: In which version of windows? You installed as normal user or admin?

Comment: As a normal user on windows it is in C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Git

Comment: Try `dir /s /b git.exe` and grab a coffee: you will have a few git.exe to play with. The advise: use the one on `program files` or on your profile.

Comment: Default location depends on the user running the installer (for git 2.33.1 on Windows 10, 21H1): if you run the installer as admin, default location is `C:\Program Files\Git`, if you run the installer as a normal user, default location is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git`

Answer (score 530):

If you're using [GitHub for Windows](https://desktop.github.com/), git.exe may not be in your PATH, but you may find it in a location like: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<numbersandletters>\bin\git.exe`

That's the situation for me, in Windows 7 + version 1.0 of GitHub for Windows.

In Windows 10 it appears to be in:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<numbersandletters>\cmd\git.exe`

( \cmd versus \bin)

**From [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) 1.1**

The UI is different and the Git path now is in:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-<appversion>\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe`

**PS:** *AppData* is a hidden folder by default.

Comment: Ironically, that's about the least portable place to put it...stop hiding things from me. Chrome, I'm looking at you too.

Comment: Nice Thx! Worked also for me on windows 8 Pro

in cmd window easy to retrieve:
dir /S /P "c:\git.exe" 
this will give you your personal location of git.exe file

Comment: It also turns out the git exe is quite nasty aswell - see [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/228592/adding-an-exe-to-default-path-without-adding-the-directory) for how to add it to your path

Comment: @AlexGidan Well, I only covered one particular installation case, and that's all I intended my answer to do (since I don't know other cases well enough). VonC's answer is actually the most complete one; it just takes more reading to get through.

Comment: Worked for me - Windows 10 & Android Studio

Comment: Its located in /cmd folder instead of /bin for me. I'm using Window 7 Pro SP1 & GitHub Desktop version 3.0.11.0

Comment: i'm on windows 10 using git for windows 2.10 and they have the exe located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe`

Comment: Github for Windows (Electron) + Windows 10 
<user>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.5.5\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin

Comment: Note that with GitHubDesktop there is a version number in the path, @codervince quoted. The correct path depends on you username and the installed version: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-<version number>\resources\app\git\` and than there is one `git.exe` in folder `cmd` and one in `mingw64\bin` - I did not figure the difference yet.

Comment: Lol different versions of Windows will have in either /cmd or /bin

Comment: I'm not sure how my specific GitHub-for-Windows case transformed into the most popular answer, but hey. Due to the nature of this answer right now (listing several possibilities for different version/OS combos), and due to my low likelihood of personally keeping it updated, I'll make this community-wiki.

Comment: Short answer for Windows: Git Bush -> `where git.exe`

Comment: On version 2.21.0 and using Windows 10 the location is C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 140):

If `git.exe` is indeed in your `%PATH%` (that is, if you can type a `git --version` in a DOS windows), then `which git.exe` will tell you where.
(provided you did install [GoW: Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki/): 130 unix commands compiled for windows, including `which`).

[Jonny Leeds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962696/jonny-leeds) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located/11928949?noredirect=1#comment33739625_11928949) that you also can use `where git.exe`
(except with Powershell, for you need to use `where.exe git.exe`, instead of the [PowerShell command `where`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16420160/6309))

If not, don't forget you can install git wherever you want, with the <del>[portable version of msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)</del>. It is just an archive you unzip in any directory of your choice.

Update 2015: [**use the portable version of "git-for-windows"**](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/), like:

[`PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.4.windows.2/PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe)

Then add to %PATH%:

- `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit\cmd`
- `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit\usr\bin`

You will not only get `git.exe`, but also 200+ executable for Unix commands! No more GnuOnWindows to install.
See more at "[Why is it that if you download Git 2.0 from the net, you always get a 1.9.4 installer package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)".

---

More recently (2017), from [Luke McGregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070291/luke-mcgregor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44624061/6309), for the new [**GitHub Desktop**](https://desktop.github.com/):

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHubDesktop\app-[gfw-version]\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe"
For instance: 
%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.1\resources\app\git\cmd
```

Comment: on windows you can use 'where' but if you are using powershell make sure to type where.exe git otherwise it will try and do something else!

Comment: @JonnyLeeds good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The Windows Vista and later one doesn't seem to work on my Windows 7 box. Fails on the 8.3 naming convention; just says directory not found if I go into the dirs one at a time.

Comment: @RobertGrant I do confirm on my W7, it is working: `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PORTAB~1\bin\git.exe"`

Comment: @RobertGrant, the file path that was suggested also did not work for me...I had to change the '~1' in 'PORTAB~1' to a '~2' because the  long string of numbers and letters in the 'PortableGit_..." folder name ends in a '2' for me and not a '1' character as VonC's must have for his installation.

Comment: %LOCALAPPDATA%\ is a terrible place to install an .exe file. Causing me grief pointing android studio to it, because it can't see inside this hidden folder. arghh why cant they use c:\program files like everyone else!

Comment: @SolarBrian Agreed. These days, I make my own path https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172186/6309, in addition of GitHub Desktop.

Comment: @VonC: After installing git for windows (non-portable), I find `git.exe` in four different folders: `git/bin/`, `git/cmd/`, `git/mingw64/bin/` and `git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/`. Do you know which one I should use, e.g. when I want to call git using Python's `subprocess`? I suppose either the one in `cmd/` or the one in `bin/` but is there a difference?

Comment: @Dennis `bin/` is enough. `cmd/` would be useful only as a folder added to the `%PATH%` in a `CMD` session.

Answer (score 100):

I'm very surprised to see that no one mentioned using the --exec-path switch.

> git --exec-path
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Not quite. On Windows, that would give me: `D:\prgs\git\latest\mingw64/libexec/git-core`, where there is indeed a `git.exe`, but not the one I use. `where git.exe` gives me the correct location: `D:\prgs\git\latest\bin\git.exe`. You can see the difference between the two in the comment of https://github.com/git/git/commit/53876fcf3fdc1c46c26fc3a191e74a06e633d5b2. exec-path reference what is called the "helper directory".

Comment: This is really interesting answer, but it does give somewhat different result than e.g.  `where git`. Also --exec-path gives slashes instead of back-slashes.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.

@VonC , If you navigate to that directory you listed:

    C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core

you should see a file, 

    git.exe

within the directory. So the full path would be:

    C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe

Did that not work for you?

Comment: @LastTigerEyes Not Program files, because I uncompress the portable archive elswhere, but yes, that does ends with `mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe`

Comment: This flag is very useful, just keep in mind that the executable will be in the root directory + /bin

Comment: Just FYI. I'm, using 'System.Diagnostics.Process' to automate git and find out that using the default path make `process` to end before gives any answer. I'm assuming that `git.exe` call the `..\git-core\git.exe`. Using the .exe pointed by --exec-path works fine.

Answer (score 41):

Just to add to a couple of answers already here:

On Windows, you can use the built in "where" instead of "which" (which is for Linux). So, `where git` will tell you the location of git assuming that it is in the system path.

If it is not in the system path, and you want a native (no downloads or installations), reasonable time command to find it, use `dir /s git.exe`

Comment: on windows 10 and within a mingw64 shell, `which git` returned a virtual location: `/mingw64/bin/git`. while `where git` returned two actual locations on the c drive: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe` and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe`

Comment: Just in case anyone else tries it, note that `where git` only works in the old CMD prompt, not in Powershell.

Of course, it also works within the gitbash environment (which is built on top of CMD and not Powershell).

Answer (score 25):

If you use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), one instance can be found here:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin
```

You can also install quickly via [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git). `choco install git` which will then make it available on your path without any further work on your part.

Comment: Which Git does Atlassian use? Is it the portable git for?

Comment: @Pacerier mine says product version is 1.9.5.msysgit.0 If that provides any clues.

Answer (score 16):

Here are step by step instructions for you to find out:

1. If you're using any version of Windows, do `Ctrl - Shift - Esc` of open Task Manager.
2. Open GitHub, and look into Task Manager.
3. There should be something like this: [image: What's in Task Manager when GitHub is open.]
4. Right click the row called `GitHub`, and select "Open file location".
5. A window should pop up, showing you where the file is.
   [image: Github.exe found!]

There you go!

You can do this with any application, not just GitHub.

Comment: This is about GitHub.exe whereas OP asked for `git.exe`.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy If you look around in the directory, you'll find git.exe

Comment: Not true for 1.0.13. See other answers.

Answer (score 15):

If you can use the git command it should be in your path?
thus this should work asuming linux or linux like os

```
which git
```

else also asuming linux like os

```
cd /
find . -name "*git*"
```

if on windows tell me what version you are using and I'll help you. The default path on windows is
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`.

The name of the executable is not `git.exe`on all systems.

Comment: When using GitHub For Windows you start the Git Shell power shell that it comes with, it has it's own PATH that you don't get by just opening up your own command prompt

Comment: Windows: `where git`

Answer (score 15):

type in the command line:

```
where git.exe
```

Comment: This indeed will work only if the file is in the path. if it is not than look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34442497/463464

Comment: it's worked for me, i'm using cmder terminal on windows 10

Comment: I had to do `where.exe git.exe`

Answer (score 11):

It seems like git.exe can be found in different places depending on how it was installed, the version, and version of Windows.

I installed Git-2.6.3-64-bit.exe (cleand install; just git, not the Github Desktop client) on Windows 10 Pro N.
This is the default location:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe

and

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin

Answer (score 7):

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<random hash>\cmd\git.exe` is where my git.exe is located on Windows 10, Git version 2.10.0.0

**Edit:** With GitHubDesktop, the location changed to this

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.1\resources\app\git\cmd
```

or the easier way

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.1\resources\app\git\cmd
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it can be at: `C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd`. Checking your PATH environment variable for USER and for SYSTEM can give you that.

Comment: while my path for git for windows is different on 8.1 /10 this answer helped me. I was selecting the wrong file. it should be exactly `git.exe` it was located in cmd/ directory. this answer helped me out.

Answer (score 6):

```
Install git first to your window from
```

https://git-scm.com/download/win

```
 Select this path while configuring with git to Android studio
    C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Answer (score 5):

Well I just searched for **git.exe** on my Windows.
Many files returned with names like `git-something.exe` and `git-somethingElse.exe`.
Out of those I could find a file with the exact name **git.exe**.
I opened the file and could see cmd with various git commands, which made me decide that it's the correct one.
Pasted the file's path (below) to PyCharm and it worked.

```
C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_cba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147f7326ad\cmd\git.exe
```

PS: I installed Git and GitHub through Windows the GitHub's Client Installation.

Answer (score 5):

Check this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 7 on GitHub 2.5.3.0 I found it in C:\Users(user)\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_(numbers)\**mingw32**\bin\git.exe

thanks to `dir /s git.exe`

Answer (score 4):

Appears to have moved again in the latest version of GH for windows to:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-[gfw-version]\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe
```

Given it now has the version in the folder structure i think it will move every time it auto-updates. This makes it impossible to put into path. I think the best option is to install git separately.

Answer (score 3):

In windows 8 I found its path as below:

[image]

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe

Comment: i didn't find it under C:\Program Files (x86) neither C:\Program Files

Comment: make sure git is installed :)

Comment: @AbdulMajeed, It could have been installed anywhere though.

Comment: Yes, I have shared default path.

Comment: That's where mine used to be installed.  On a new Windows install it seems to have installed it as default into the appdata\local folder

Answer (score 3):

If you've got the PowerShell-based git installation, you can use the Get-Command object to find git:

```
Get-Command git.exe | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10:

I installed git from - https://git-for-windows.github.io/.

After installation i found it at `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

Comment: I answered the question cause I am using a 64Bit machine with windows 10 and above is the result of my installation which I did not find in the answer to the question. I am puzzled by seeing a -1 on my answer? Could anyone explain to me  why it was downvoted?

Comment: Not sure why, this seems accurate. +1

Comment: it's an inaccurate and incomplete answer. i don't know if it's a group policy or a configuration chosen during installation, but that git installer when run on windows 10 does under certain circumstances install to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Programs\` instead of `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Note that the question is about Git**Hub** for Windows, not *git for Windows*.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who might not find the other solutions suitable,

I just today downloaded the newest version and the git.exe was located in

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.10\resources\app\git\cmd
```

Comment: I'm also seeing it in `<root>\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin'. That one is much larger ... I wonder what the difference is ... They are both returning the same version info.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub Desktop team member here

> What is the PATH to git.exe?

The version of Git used in GitHub Desktop (or GitHub for Windows) is not intended to be used directly by users, as the path will changes between updates and it might lack some features you need.

I recommend installing [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) which will be installed at a predictable location under `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) installed, the path would look like `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe` on a 64-bit system, otherwise just download and install it, PyCharm doesn't come with Git client.

Comment: PyCharm does come with an option to use github for all documents.

Comment: @AngusMoore, GitHub integration uses GitHub API and doesn't depend on git binary, but you still need git installed on the local machine to clone projects and commit/push.

Comment: For those who installed git extensions (windows) this is also the default location of git.exe

Answer (score 1):

First ,you should install github in your PC;
Second,you can download the tool '[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)';
Third,open the tool everything ,type *git.exe*,then you will find the location and copy the location to PyCharm ,and Test,you will see successfully!

Answer (score 1):

On windows if you have git installed through cygwin (open up cygwin and type `git --version` to check) then the path will most likely be something like `C:\cygwin64\bin\git.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I am working on OSX, and saw this issue. I found xcode disabled git, causing me to agree to the T&Cs again. I fixed by:

1. in a terminal window, within my project folder: `git status`
2. I recieved the following log entry: `Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.`
3. I ran the following: `sudo git status`
4. I then agreed to the T&Cs and everything was hunky dory

Comment: added this osx answer for those who miss the tag for windows when searching

Answer (score 1):

I found it at

```
C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<some_identifier>\mingw32\libexec\git-core\
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Git For Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) then it is located at

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
```

It is nice to have in mind that [Git For Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) offers **Git CMD**, a command prompt with the PATH already set. **Git CMD** is available as a shortcut in

```
Start Menu > Programs > Git
```

among other options.

Answer (score 1):

Using

- Git 2.11.0,
- Windows 10,
- Android studio 2.2

git.exe location:

> C:\Users\<.username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe

Suggestion: while Installing, copy the git path

Answer (score 1):

After running through this for all answers, did not find path though.
The latest githubdesktop.exe for windows 10 goes into this directory:

```
C:\ProgramData\<User>\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.13\GitHubDesktop.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`. I have been able to use `git.exe` located there to setup my repository with PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2022 installed, git.exe is located here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded stub from https://desktop.github.com
After installation of the git from the stub, git.exe is stored in the following location.

`C:\Users\**User Name**\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_****Some No/characters***\cmd\git.exe`

In Windows 10 64 bit, I feel the exe file is now stored in cmd folder rather than bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you've downloaded the latest version try looking in the CMD folder. git.exe should be in there and should work. You may have to input it's path manually with File>Settings>Version Control>Git

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10, Pycharm 2016.1.2 and here is the path that i found Github.exe at:   (please note that the bold part is variable and you should replace it with applicable values...)

C:\Users**Salman**\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_**c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad**\bin\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows 10: `C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_624c8416ee51e205b3f892d1d904e06e6f3c57c8\mingw32\bin\git.exe`

Comment: the hash is not always the same

Answer (score 0):

Locating and setting Git Path

- To Locate git.exe inside your Git-software installation directory.

The location for git.exe will vary depending on what Git-software you have installed! The git.exe file is located inside your Git-software installation directory, usually inside a folder called bin.
Some examples of standard locations:
Software    Standard location
Git         C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
SmartGit    C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\bin\git.exe
GitHub For Windows  C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_'numbersandletters'\cmd\git.exe

-Path Setting for Git

Set the git.exe path in the PATH environment variable

Right-click My Computer on your desktop or start-menu, and select Properties.
Click the Advanced system settings tab.
Click the Environment Variables button.
Under System Variables, click PATH (can also be called Path) and click Edit.
Paste the location to your git.exe* and ok.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_\cmd\git.exe

This is the location that worked for me. I was unable to use git from the shell as well. Setting the above location as the path fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with GitHub Desktop 1.0.13 and I wanted to add `git.exe` to my Intellij ennvironment. 
I have found it in `C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.13\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`

Comment: When adding answers to an older question it is helpful to explain how you answer differs from the existing answers and indicate which new information you are adding that applies to the question.