# Github, Github for Windows, on every commit generates us.stackdump

Tags: github, stack-trace, crash-dumps, git-commit, github-for-windows

Since I started using Github for managing my projects I receive dump file on every commit.

I am using

```
 a) GitHub (private repositories for my personal projects)
 b) GitHub for windows GitHub client
```

When I sync my commits after finish (or may be during commit) it generates "**us.stackdump**" file.

This is the file contents:

```
@@ -0,0 +1,18 @@
+MSYS-1.0.12 Build:2011-07-20 17:52
+Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=68085E34
+eax=68560000 ebx=000073CC ecx=00001CF3 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=68560000
+ebp=0028FE48 esp=0028FE3C program=us
+cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
+Stack trace:
+Frame     Function  Args
+0028FE48  68085E34  (68560000, 00000000, 000073CC, 00000004)
+0028FE98  68001CB0  (00442D24, 00000001, 0028FEE8, 680044EA)
+0028FEE8  680045C7  (00000000, 00000000, 0028FF28, 0040C1AC)
+0028FF08  68004C5F  (00401A40, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
+0028FF28  68004C98  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
+0028FF58  0040C0BC  (00401A40, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
+0028FF88  0040103D  (7EFDE000, 0028FFD4, 77C69EF2, 7EFDE000)
+0028FF94  76AC33AA  (7EFDE000, 772F991B, 00000000, 00000000)
+0028FFD4  77C69EF2  (00401000, 7EFDE000, 00000000, 00000000)
+0028FFEC  77C69EC5  (00401000, 7EFDE000, 00000000, 78746341)
+End of stack trace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the [msysgit issue (in progress) 25](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/25), with one only suggestion for now:

> replace msys-1.0.dll by a new one in "documents and settings\administrator\local setting\application data\github\portablegit_xxxx..."

Try *first* to commit with the [msysgit included in GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127984/6309), and see if the issue persists.

Launch a session through

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_93...\git-cmd.bat
```

Or through the icon "Git Shell", which launches:

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

Comment: Thank @VonC, I will try it today and will update you hopefully by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17253219/868538) didn't work for me but along the same lines:

1. Download [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)
2. Copy the whole MSYS bin directory into the Git bin directory.