# How to install Git Shell

Tags: windows, git, shell

Windows 7 Ultimate

I used to have Git Shell installed. The icon is grey with a cat face. It was either installed by the Git or by GitHub for Windows.

Somehow I've lost it.

I've tried re-installing both Git and GitHub for Windows, but I can't get it back.

Comment: Sounds like the GitHub logo.

Comment: Yes it looked similar to the GitHub icon.  It was a "git enabled" shell. Maybe they got rid of it ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you have [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) (installed, it should come with your shortcut.

It is a shortcut to:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

More recent versions of G4W (see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23918254/6309)) could have it at:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Apps\2.0\...\...\
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

If that shell complains about the absence of `git`, launch "G4W" itself, which will extract git.
See "[Where is `git.exe` located?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/6309)".

As mentioned below, to restore the shortcut, after having run the first command, execute in the Git shell:

```
github --reinstall-shortcuts
```

Comment: Yes I have GitHub for Windows installed and yes I have the shortcut you mention ( light blue icon with cat face ).  But I am looking for a shortcut to Git-enabled shell ( dark grey icon with cat face ). I wonder if they removed it in latest G4W installer ?

Comment: OK i see that your link does invoke the shell as I expect ... still wonder what happened to the icon though

Comment: Thank you so much. The missing icon for the Git Shell was really bothering me. This helped!

Comment: Was having the same issue trying to open the git shell. Cheers VonC!!

Answer (score 30):

Try running the following command:

`github --reinstall-shortcuts`

That repaired the Git Shell shortcut for me, and also put the proper icon back.

Comment: Thanks for this. Mine disappeared when I update to Windows 8.1 and subsequently updated Git.

Answer (score 6):

I found out that the answer that you specifically wanted involves a combination of the previous answers:
1. Running the Git Shell via the command line (Since you lost the shortcut)

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

2. Once youre in the Git Shell run the command in the previous answer

```
github --reinstall-shortcuts
```

You'll find the Git Shell with the grey cat icon that originally came with the GitHub setup in the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

> Windows 10
>   Git-2.19.0-64

The Git Shell is installed by default in:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
```

Try create a shortcut to your desktop, not sure if this answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The direct link for Git Shell is now:

https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today, and since this is the first Google result for my query trying to find a solution, I'll post what I sorted here.

It looks like GitHub for Windows installs some or all of itself into `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Apps\2.0\...\...\`* and this reference was broken on Git Shell .lnk shortcut on the desktop.  The GitHub.exe file pointed to did not exist; the entire path was missing.

I viewed properties on the .lnk file (select Properties from context menu or ALT+ENTER on keyboard with .lnk selected) and clicked the Change Icon button.  A message box appeared noting that the path to the old icon file was missing and what the bad path was.

I found the "current" path by poking about in the above noted directory and finding GitHub.exe again.  The icon is one of three available in GitHub.exe; I expect this is what some of the other answers (like the reinstall-shortcuts suggestion) accomplish.

Hope this helps someone!

- (Which seems to be normal for .NET ClickOnce applications; those `...` are randomized/obfuscated/generated so they will look like gibberish.  My specific *working* path, as an example, ended up being: `C:\Users\anshou\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RZ33EP02.2J7\5OMOZAGM.89T\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0001.0003_e68db37a99107794` -- note that this path is not truncated, that is the exact path, double period and all.)