# Can git be used as a subsystem shell like ftp or mysql?

Tags: git, shell

Does GIT have a shell mode available like many other command line tools, like MYSQL? The designers appear to have gone to great lengths to avoid the need for a "modal" interface, including that the DOS prompt can change when a GIT directory happens to be the working directory. This is great, but is there a command line argument or another method one can use to drop into a GIT subsystem shell?

Rationale: With GUI interfaces available today it is VERY rare (never) that I would actually want to enter a DOS command while using GIT. Therefore, why should I have to enter GIT to start every command, with the disadvantage that it takes extra keystrokes and that I can cause damage if I forget: some GIT command names overlap with DOS commands.

Comment: *What* Git commands overlap with DOS commands?  If you're going to do anything in Git you have to prefix it with `git`.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense since you'd need some moe change or command prefix to run plain shell commands like `cd`, `vi somefile.c`, `make` or you'd need two console windows and switch between both. In the end this would probably reduce the productivity rather than increasing it.

Comment: Not natively, but you might want to look at [`gitsh`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh).

Comment: Perhaps it's more of a mindset thing... There is *one* `git` command, and it's name is `git`. It just happens to have many different arguments/options/subcommands... `git` is not a shell.

Answer (score -2):

<del>Yes, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457182/how-to-install-git-shell) (which you really should have found if you did even a cursory search of SO), there is a git shell for Windows.</del>

I did not notice the github-only aspect...

Comment: The OP isn't simply looking for a command line version, but for a "Git shell" that would show, for example, a `git>` prompt and accept git commands. Also, the OP asks about Git, but your answer is GitHub specific.