# How to install Git Shell for Windows?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-shell

My research led me to install GitHub Desktop (for Windows), as it seemed like Git Shell would be installed at the same time. However, I got Git Bash - not Git Shell.

I need Git Shell for an installation, but it doesn't seems obvious how to install it. Help would've been highly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by git shell ? git bash is a shell with git commands in it.

Comment: Previous versions of Github Desktop came with 'Git Shell' which was powershell with (posh) git, but they seem to have removed it in their latest incarnation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simmilar qestion Check it out here --> ([how to install git shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457182/how-to-install-git-shell))

If you have GitHub for Windows (installed, it should come with your shortcut.

It is a shortcut to:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

More recent versions of G4W (see answer below) could have it at:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Apps\2.0\...\...\
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

If that shell complains about the absence of git, launch "G4W" itself, which will extract git.
See ["Where is git.exe located?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located/11928949#11928949).

As mentioned below, to restore the shortcut, after having run the first command, execute in the Git shell:

```
github --reinstall-shortcuts
```

**UPDATE:** my Shell.exe is located in here:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

or depends where you installed it.

```
C:\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

Once i run it as administrator it opens and works.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have browsed both those location and I have only:
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\GitHub Desktop.exe".
It doesn't seem like the Git Shell came with my installation. Could it possibly have been erased from recent updates?

Comment: @Mykita i just updated my answer this works for me it could be located there

Comment: C:\Git\bin\sh.exe - There it was! Thanks a bunch Wojtek!

Comment: Confirmed.  I just did a binary comparison on these files. C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe and C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe are identical.

I'm guessing that this was intended to make it "easier" to find the Git shell, independent of whether it is known as "Git Shell" or "Git Bash".  Unfortunately, this also causes some confusion, because they are literally different files, but also literally identical (other than their names).  So "Git Shell" and "Git Bash" are both the same thing, and yet not quite.  Grr.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the shell is no longer included with GitHub Desktop.