# android: Cannot run program CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I keep on getting the following error message from eclipse when I try to push my android code to my remote Git repository in Bitbucket.

```
Cannot run program "C:\Users\John\.ssh": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

I have already performed a successful push once to the remote repository of my entire android project via:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myname/myproject.git
```

I have also exchanged public keys between the android and the Bitbucket account. Both eclipse id_rsa public and private keys are stored under my C:/Users/John/.ssh folder

I have also set the environmental variable GIT_SSH=C:/Users/John/.ssh

Now every time I try to push to the remote repository eclipse complains with this error.

My eclipse is Android Developer Tools running on Windows 8.1.

I appreciate any support from the community.

Answer (score 31):

I found that the path in Android Studio (File-Settings-Version Control->Git->Path to Git) requires not just the path where Git.exe is, but also needs to include the file name git.exe at the end of the path. When I included that this error goes. Hope this helps. You can test it with the Test button next to the path and browse buttons.

Comment: Sir, sir that is impossible I spent hours on this and was about to post my own question. Thank you. Honestly thanks so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/4645236

my git.exe was in 
`~\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_blahblah#sandLetters\cmd`

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot. first link to open up and i was able to fix it right away :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes absolutely !

This is the faulty one:

```
C:\Users\Zozo07\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d76a6a98c9315931ec4927243517bc09e9b731a0\cmd

C:\Users\Zozo07\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d76a6a98c9315931ec4927243517bc09e9b731a0\cmd\git.exe
```

The `\git.exe` at the end has solved my problem !

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File-> Settings-> Version Control -> Git** and in the text box "**Path to Git Executable** " give the path to the git.exe file. **eg: E:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe**. Then click the test button. If the path is correct it will pop up a dialog box with the details about the installed git version.