# how do I find the git bin folder?

Tags: git, windows-7

Whenever I try to use git commands it says

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

One of the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/27313207#27313207?newreg=ba84046de5df4d84a87f526d9dc8e774) says I need to 
"add the path to your git bin folder." However, I cannot locate anything called `git.bin` or anything similar. I can find a folder with a `git` but the word `bin` isn't present anywhere...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `git.exe` is what you want. Not `git.bin`. Windows command line executables end in `.exe`. In the case of a GPL program, it's sometimes in a `bin` folder, but not always. Put the path to `git.exe` in your Windows `PATH`.

Comment: actually I was wrong I have a github of type "click once application Reference" adding the file location of this to the path has not helped.

Comment: Right. You double click the GitHub icon, but then, what does it do? It probably calls `git.exe` and can't find it. You don't want to add the path to `GitHub` to your `PATH`. As I mentioned in my prior comment, you needto add the full directory path of `git.exe` to your `PATH`.

Comment: I can't find a git.exe anywhere

Comment: I'm confused. In your problem statement, you say, *I can find a folder with a `git.exe`...* If you found that folder, you need to put the full path of that folder into `PATH`. If not, you can find it with Windows 7 search in the Explorer. Open explorer, go to the top of the `C:\ ` drive, and type `git.exe`, then wait awhile for it to search. The link you gave to the other problem shows an example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`. Did you try going under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git` and looking there?

Comment: i confused the "click once application Reference" for an exe if i search the c drive it doesn't find a git.exe

Comment: Look under `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files` or `C:\` for a `Git` folder. If there isn't one, then maybe `git` wasn't installed properly.

Comment: there are no git files in either of these locations.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located

Comment: thankyou its working now. the portable git folder in the screenshot contained a bin folder and when I directed the path to it it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple sollution. You need to use "git shell" to directly use the keyword **git**. Github (windows) program come together with a powershell client. Just enter the keyword "git shell" in windows search. 
[image]
This shortcut will open the powershell which will recognize the **git** command