# Cannot implement git version control on R-Studio (Version Control System: NONE)

Tags: r, git, bash

I'm trying to put a project under version control in R-Studio.  I have installed git and everything is working from the git bash command-line.  However, when I go to Tools >> Version Control in R-Studio, it says "None" under "Version Control System."

I have attached a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBMKy.png

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the dropdown?

Comment: Yes... there's nothing in it.

Comment: Did you specify the path to the git executable in Global Options (not project options)?

Comment: Embarrassingly, no.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 10 users, even if you had git lovingly installed at:

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe

At some stage the update install moves it into your AppData directory. Thanks Redmond. (I think around Git 2.6.4)

**TO FIX**:

1. Make sure like @arvi1000 says above "Did you specify the path to the git executable in Global Options (not project options)? " - set path first in **Global options** in `Rstudio` under Tools
2. Change path under Git/SVN the **Git Executable path** from Program files to new location of `git.exe` now in Appdata. e.g. for my userprofile Info:

> C:\Users[Your user profile "Info"]\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin

3. Now look in RStudio **Project Options** under Git/SVN to set Version Control System.

**MORE HELP**

See these answers in this thread [for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33954946/4606130) and if you cannot find `git.exe` this is [a helpful search tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34107846/4606130).

Answer (score 3):

Even after setting the path to the git executable on my Mac at "Macintosh HD/usr/bin", RStudio still showed "None" for the version control option. In Terminal, I entered "config git" and was greeted by the message that I had to agree to the new Xcode/iOS license. I was able to do that in Terminal by typing "sudo xcodebuild", entering my admin password, then scrolling to the end of the agreement text and entering "agree". Then git showed up as an option for version control. I mention this in case others are stymied even after setting the path to the git executable.