# can I install msysgit after having github installed so I can use native cmd console?

Tags: vim, github, msysgit, vundle, ultisnips

I following instructions to install Ultisnips plugin for VIM which calls for installing  Vundle plugin manager and it calls for installing msysGit for native cmd console, but I have GitHub already installed. Will this break my GitHub config? [Platform is Win 7 Pro 64]

Answer (score 0):

No: the [`git.exe` used by GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/6309) is independent from any other msysgit installation.

Both might use the same global [%HOME%.gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115116/6309) though.