# understanding cmd "git version'

Tags: git, github

I have Git installed on my Windows 8.1 machine and I have also installed GitHub for windows on that machine.

When I open cmd prompt and type "git version" it returns:

```
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
```

When I open the Git Shell from the Github for Windows app the same "git version" command returns:

```
git version 1.9.5.github.0
```

I don't understand why they are not the same or how to interpret the msygit.1 and the github.0 portions.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you have two different installations of Git. First is the one you installed with MySysgit. Second is the one bundled with Github for Windows.

I have not used either of the software (I use Linux.); I am just *sherlocking* based on your statements.

Comment: This is correct. GitHub for Windows bundles its own Git. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16127984/354577, for example.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the confirmation Chris. :)