# Github 3.0.11 does not have git.exe - how to integrate with Android-Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I'm using Android-Studio 1.5 on Windows 10, with a recently upgraded GitHub Desktop (3.0.11), and now having problems with the integration of GitHub and Android-Studio.

After updating GitHub to the new GitHub Desktop version last week, I'd not had any problems until today.  Android-Studio reported that it could not find git.exe where it was previously located (C:\Users\Mxxx\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565cb218a521411d0e854079a28c\bin).  Following the posts of many others here, I did various searches - no file by the name of "git.exe" exists on my machine any more.  In the previously used folder there is a "rebase.exe".

Using Task Manager, as suggested by ProgramsFast in response to this related question ([Where is git.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located/33954946#33954946)), I found that GitHub desktop was running GitHub.exe.  So, I changed the settings of Android-Studio to point to the respective version of GitHub.exe (C:\Users\Mxxx\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\0A0P98AA.GDB\CH7VMOKM.2V1\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0000_328216539257acd4\GitHub.exe).  The connection test failed - as the --version test of git.exe failed (of course).  However the EventLog message for Git disappeared.  So I started using it.

However, I have found that every time Gradle does a sync, a new GitHub Desktop window opens, even if there was already one open.

Have I got the settings right, and this is a fault of Android-Studio?  Or is there something I have done wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

I have found one way forward - installing Git GUI (2.6.4) for Windows.  This has provided a git.exe version that Android-Studio immediately configured into its settings. As the interface is quite different to the Git Hub UI, not sure I like it yet, but Android-Studio does not appear to have any issues integrating with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a git.exe here

> C:\Users\[*username*]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_'numbersandletters'\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

With the latest GitHub Desktop, I found git.exe here:

> C:\Users\[*username*]\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.7.2\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

Set your system `PATH` to point at the Git installation.

Modifying `PATH` (Windows 10):

1. On the Windows Desktop, search/right-click **My Computer**
2. In the pop-up menu, click **Properties**
3. In the **System Properties** window, click the **Advanced** tab, then click **Environment Variables**
4. In **System Variables**, highlight **Path**, and click **Edit**
5. In the **Edit system variables** window, click **New**

Add the following paths to `PATH`:

- `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\`
- `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\`

Confirm that these paths are correct. You may have Git installed on a different drive, or in `Program Files (x86)`.