# git on command line using github git

Tags: python, git, github-for-windows

I have github git 2.14.1 installed on Windows 10 from this URL:
https://git-scm.com/download/win

How do I get access to the git command such that I can invoke it from the cmd or powershell commandline?

What I really want to do is invoke it from Python using `subprocess.Popen('somepath/git log --follow' ...)`, but I figure if I can run it from the commandline then I can do that in Python.

Previously I was able to follow these instructions on my windows 7 machine with an older version of git:
[Where is git.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located)

In short, I am looking here:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<numbersandletters>\cmd\git.exe`
and the git.exe file does not exist.

So I think either something changed in github install or on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default setup, git should just be in your PATH, so you can just open a cmd.exe window(or find git bash on your start menu for a better experience) and run git without using any full path to git.exe file.
From python you can then just run `subprocess.Popen('git log ... '`

If you do need the full path, Git for Windows installs git.exe by default at `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`