# Team City execute Git script

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am running TeamCity (9.x) on Windows under the local system account.  I have installed mysysgit on the server also.  I want to run a script via TC using a command line build step that pushes to a git repo. The repo is secure so team city must authenticate.  How do I achieve this? The credential-store is per user so not sure how I could store the creds under the local system context.  Access to git is over http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to not install the [obsolete msysgit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309), but the new [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/).

> I want to run a script via TC using a command line build step that pushes to a git repo. The repo is secure so team city must authenticate.

All you need is to use an http url which includes the username.

```
https://<username>@yourserver/<username>/<barerepo.git>
```

You can then set a git config credential.helper netrc which will look for %HOME%_netrc file for the username and password.
I [use an encrypted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309), but since TC wouldn't be able to enter the gpg private key passphrase anyway, you are better off experimenting with an `_netrc` file in plain text.

```
machine yourserver
login username
password a_password
protocol https
```

Make sure the global setting is set for the same user account as the one used by TeamCity to run.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell it is a literal command, which will make git call the [`git-credential-netrc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc) in order to get the password for a given user and http url.

Comment: yep, got it..windows caught me out by adding .txt to the _netrc file.  works now, thanks

Comment: where is git.exe now that I have installed the latest git for windows?

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell http://stackoverflow.com/a/7671364/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/6309: with the setup, it probably is in `C:\Program files\Git\bin\git.exe`.

Comment: On my server, "system" didn't have the "HOME" environmental variable set. I fixed this by adding the following line to the beginning of my powershell script:
`set-variable -Force HOME C:\home`. This allowed git to find the credentials in c:\home\_netrc