# Intellij - Cannot Run Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have noticed that on Version Control window, in tabs *Log* and *Local changes* there is no information. Only following error appears:

**Error updating changes: Cannot identify version of git executable C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe**

When I have clicked Test in Settings > Version Control > Git, entered above path in *Path to Git executable* following window appeared: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35zIL.png)

After typing in CMD command **git --version** I get output:

```
git version 2.17.0.windows.1
```

What is more after writing some code Intellij is not highlighting changes.

I don't have any idea why it is not working... Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make Git work with IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671305/how-do-you-make-git-work-with-intellij)

Comment: Yeah, thank you. After implementing solutions from link you provided issue still exists. But I am almost sure that cause of this error comes from my VDI machine.

Comment: This started to fail in my windows 10 box today (16/01/2020)
`C:\>git.exe --version
error reading exit code: The handle is invalid.`

Answer (score 15):

I am able to resolve the issue.

My GIT installation directory: C:\installations\Git\

**WHAT WORKED**

If I point the Git executable path to (C:\installations\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe) it worked.

[image]

**WHAT DIDN'T WORKED**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For me, only invalidating caches and restarting intellij worked. :)

Comment: Worked for me; thanks! I hadn't made any config changes...my Mac had just forcibly restarted and when it came back up IntelliJ decided I didn't have git installed anymore, even though I was successfully using git from the cmd line.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me in Mac osx

```
~ ⌚ 8:00:57
$ which git   
/Users/shashwat/.aw/pex_resources/scripts/binaries/git
```

Ans setting the path in Intellij
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, IntelliJ cannot get any output from the command line client. Something similar is reported - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82445

It might be caused by antivirus software or UAC.

Answer (score 2):

1. go to the terminal and type `git --exec-path` to get your git path.
2. then go to IntelliJ and configure it, Click browse and select your git path.
3. select git and hit test.

Note: on Mac Os, use `/` in finder to navigate easier.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem, and the config is right,

git works just when i cut down the internet,  it got from the IT  part in my company.