# How to add existing IntelliJ project to Git/GitHub with history?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm fairly new to Git. I recently started a project in Java using IntelliJ, not realizing that I should have connected to Git/GitHub before writing code. I now want to connect the project to Git/GitHub, but with previous versions of the project committed (this is the part I'm having trouble with). I have access to the project history in IntelliJ, if that helps. How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make Git work with IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671305/how-do-you-make-git-work-with-intellij)

Comment: So you're saying you didn't use any version control system and only have access to the "local history" feature in IDEA? I guess you should be able to export that to a git repository somehow.

Answer (score 2):

My full understanding is that you want to go back to the code when you first started your project. If my understanding is correct, you can check it out here. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html#restore-changes-from-local-history