# unable to integrate git in Intellij community version : Git is not installed Empty git --version output:

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

[image]

Enable to use git in IntelliJ community edition.

`"ERROR DETAILS" : "Git is not installed Empty git --version output:"`

after a long fight with the installation, I was unable to fix it

Comment: can someone help me fixing this issue ..i struggled a lot but  couldn't able to fix it

Comment: is git installed?

Comment: if installed, have you added git path to PATH in environment variables

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the "download and install" button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make Git work with IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671305/how-do-you-make-git-work-with-intellij)

Comment: Tried everything but nothing worked